# LTSpice: Time step too small?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

I am trying to create an integrator op amp circuit for a lab, but Spice is not happy for some reason. The error message: "Analysis: Time step too small; time = 0.006, timestep = 1.25e-018: trouble with lmf1:qx-instance q:lmf1:1"
When I change the capacitance to 0.01uF (Which is not what the lab wants) it runs fine with no error.

Here is the screenshot of the schematic and waveforms:
[image]

I would greatly appreciate some help figuring out what's wrong

Comment: Try using a non 741 op-amp model. Try stuff even putting a 0.001 ohm resistor in series with the capacitor. Fiddle with it until it works i.e. experiment.

Comment: 1 ns risetime on your pulse source is nonsense with a 741, increase it to something sensible like 1 us

Comment: Are you restricted to using the 741? It looks like not, since you tried `.inc opamp.sub`. Just choose `[Opamps]/UniversalOpamp2`, with some settings it can be used for just about any case out there. Otherwise, besides the other suggestions, also try adding `Rser=10m Cpar=1m` to the supplies.

Comment: That LM741.MOD file from TI's website is junk and causes convergence issues.  Try one of the two alternatives found in this forum post, or try some of the numbered suggestions too to get around the non-convergence: https://forum.kicad.info/t/op-amp-simulation-wrong-saturation/24873/10?u=ste

Comment: @a concerned citizen -i had a similar issue with a simulation of an H-bridge, and your suggestion of adding Rser=10m and Cpar=1m to my sources worked.  Why is that ? What does that do for the solver?  Thanks